# React Native App with Adjust SDK: Account Removal and High-Risk Behavior

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, sdk

I'm encountering an issue with the Adjust SDK in my React Native app, and I could use some guidance. I've included the Adjust SDK for tracking specific features in my app and even mentioned it in the questionnaire while publishing and the privacy policy URL. However, I'm facing an unexpected problem where my account is being removed, and I'm flagged for high-risk behavior.

Is there anyone who has experience with using the Adjust SDK in React Native apps and has encountered similar issues? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this problem programmatically or if there are specific configurations I need to consider.

I integrated the Adjust SDK into my React Native app for feature tracking with the aim of future improvements and explicitly mentioned that on the questionnaire while publishing and in my privacy policy URL. I expected that my account would remain active, and there wouldn't be any high-risk behavior flags. However, despite trying different devices and completely different accounts to publish again, my account was repeatedly removed, and I continued to be flagged for high-risk behavior.